# C++ Simple Pointer mistake can't figure out why?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to design a StudentReviewSystem, which simply has courses, students, etc. Now, I am trying to add a course object to the courses array. Since, I am doing it dynamically; when I insert a new course, I copy the olders to new array and insert new one. However, when I delete the older array it gives me invalid pointer error. I cannot figure out why? Thanks for help.

```
void StudentReviewSystem::addCourse(int courseId, string courseName) {
    //increment number of courses
    setNumCourses(numCourses + 1);
    Course* newCourses = new Course[numCourses];

    if (courses != NULL) {
        // copy courses to new one
        for (int i = 0; i < numCourses - 1; i++) {
            newCourses[i].setCourseId(courses[i].getCourseId());
            newCourses[i].setCourseName(courses[i].getCourseName());
        }

        // delete old courses
        delete courses;
    }

    newCourses[numCourses - 1].setCourseId(courseId);
    newCourses[numCourses - 1].setCourseName(courseName);
    courses = newCourses;
}
```

This is courses class.

```
#include "Course.h"
Course::Course() {
}

Course::~Course() {
}

int Course::getCourseId() const {
    return courseId;
}

void Course::setCourseId(int courseId2) {
    courseId = courseId2;
}

string Course::getCourseName() const {
    return courseName;
}

void Course::setCourseName(string courseName2) {
    courseName = string(courseName2);
}
```

And this is the main.

```
int main() {
    StudentReviewSystem srs;

    srs.addCourse(111, "foo");

    srs.addCourse(222, "foo");

    srs.addCourse(333, "foo");

    srs.addCourse(444, "foo");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour if you're using C++ and check out `std::vector<>` which will take this pain away from you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [deleting dynamic array in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101172/deleting-dynamic-array-in-c)

Comment: `delete courses;` may not call your destructors. If `courses` is an array, use ` delete [] courses;`.

Comment: Just search for "StudentReviewSystem" here and you'll find your homework has already been done.

Comment: @Roddy:  I guess StackOverflow is also TeachingAssistantOverflow?  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot something: `delete [] courses;` actually deletes the array - you were only deleting the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your problem, but I'd like to show you could do this with the standard library. One way is std::map, one is std::vector.

I suggest a map:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
std::map<int, string> courses;
```

To add a course:

```
courses[111] = "foo";
```

Number of courses:

```
courses.size();
```

Or you could use std::vector instead.

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<Course> courses;
```

To add:

```
courses.push_back(Course(111, "foo"));
```

Number of courses look the same as with map.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but i need to do this in that way.

Comment: It seems that OP doesn't need "always-sorted". if so, using `std::vector<>` is much better for performance.